# Linux - resize boot partition

Tags: linux, boot-partition

[If this has already been asked/answered, I didn't see it. Please just direct me to the answer. Thanks!]

I want to increase the size of my boot partition. If I copy the drive to another one, can I then (try to) increase the Boot partition size? How effective is this usually? Suggested size of boot drive (it's 20GB now).

Comment: 20 gigs is huge for a boot partition. Did you mean root partition?  Do you know the partition layout? Are you using lvm? Increasing the size of a boot partition is a PITa because it comes before the root partition and is not typically on LVM.  Increasing the root partition is a lot easier - but the how depends on your disk layout.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest request gives the following options:

1. [What size boot partition is recommended on Debian 11](https://linuxhint.com/boot-partition-size-debian/)

> 256 MB / 512 MB

2. [Ubuntu Boot Partition Full](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_partition_full/)

> 256 MB / 512 MB

3. [What is the recommended size for a Linux /boot partition?](https://serverfault.com/q/334663)

> Up to 1024 MiB

***NOTE: Therefore, your choice for the boot partition 20G looks more than unreasonable!***

Comment: As commented under the question itself. the OP is probably confused. Not likely this to be about the /boot which isn't even necessary nor recommended for most usage scenarios as a separated partition. This is probably about the root partition.