# /boot partition gets full using mintUpdate

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have a 1gb `/boot` partition, which should be more than enough according to all the advises I see (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1691305/linux-resize-boot-partition), [or here](https://superuser.com/questions/66015/installing-ubuntu-do-i-really-need-a-boot-partition) )

I keep my system updated using the mintUpdate utility. After today's update, I see that my boot partition is FULL. Apparently I have more than 1gb of kernel files, which is insane...

Apt indicate that I have a lot of "installed and no longer required" kernel package. So there are 6 installed versions (from `-105` to `-117`) of:

- `linux-header-5.4.0-XXX`
- `linux-header-5.4.0-XXX-generic`
- `linux-image-5.4.0-XXX-generic`
- `linux-modules-5.4.0-XXX-generic`
- `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-XXX-generic`
- `linux-tools-5.13.0-XX-generic`
- `linux-hwe-5.13-tools-5.13.0-XX`

(see full list [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Ntz1UXgv))

Questions are :

- Why doesn't `mintUpdate` clean after himself? Surely he should not keep 6 version of the kernel, nor should he saturate the boot partition...
- I ran out of space during the installation. How can I ensure that the most recent kernel version is correctly installed? (I don't dare to reboot now...). `uname -a` result is `Linux GLaDOS 5.4.0-120-generic`. Is it a sufficient proof that `5.4.0-120` is correctly installed?
- What is the correct way to uninstall old kernel version? `Apt autoremove`? Should I use `--purge`?

Note:

- Under linux Mint 20.3
- Using UEFI so there is also a 240mb `/boot/efi` partition, which is far from being full

Comment: Try removing unused kernels with this one liner: `echo $(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p') $(dpkg --list | grep linux-headers | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p') | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`  (or remove the last piped commands to stop at the actual removal first if you want). Then run apt-update and if all is well give it a reboot I think.

Comment: How is that more efficient than an apt autoremove? Apt do tell me that old linux images are unused. My question is more about why mintupdate didn't clean this himself

Comment: Perhaps mintupdate does run autoremove, but the latter is in my experience pretty conservative for kernel-related stuff for some reason. So sometimes you have to do it manually if you're getting space issues.